# Using sed to find and replace recursively

Tags: ruby, bash, recursion, sed, chef-infra

I am using a chef recipe to update a configuration file on my node.The contents of the file look something like follows:

```
server server1.domain.com
server server2.domain.com
```

I have a ruby array defined in my attribute file as follows:

```
default['servers'] = %w(xyz.domain.com abc.domain.com)
```

I want to use sed recursively to replace the server values in the file, such that my file is updated as such:

```
server xyz.domain.com
server abc.domain.com
```

I tried the following ruby loop in my recipe:

```
(node['servers']).each_with_index do |ntserver,index|
bash "server set"  do

    code <<-EOH
    sed -i 's|server .*|server #{node['servers'].at(index)}|' /etc/ntp.conf
    EOH

    end
end
```

But after the chef-client is ran and the changes are applied respectively, the contents of configuration file are as follows:

```
server abc.domain.com
server abc.domain.com
```

I am new to sed command so can't figure out where i'm going wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

By design you should not modify files with Chef. Instead you overwrite the whole file with [cookbook_file](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cookbook_file.html) resource or, if you need to insert some dynamic values into the file, with [template](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html) resource.

Comment: +1 See: http://sysadvent.blogspot.ie/2012/12/day-24-twelve-things-you-didnt-know.html#item_2

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` command (the way you use it) is quite simple; it only performs (inplace in the given file due to the `-i` option) a substitution of each string matching the pattern `server .*` by the string `server #{node['servers'].at(index)}`.  It does this throughout the whole file, so each loop changes all occurrences in the whole file.

What bothers me is that you write that in the original version you've got `server1.domain.com` but in the pattern you've got `server .*` (meaning `server`, followed by a space , and any amount of other characters `.*`).  Because of the space, this should not match anything, so nothing should be changed at all.  But maybe you just put that space in there by mistake when posting your question.  I'll assume that there was no such space in your actual code because this way it would fit the observed phenomenon.

So, to change only one line at a time, you should have a counter in your loop and have the number of the iteration in the search pattern, so that it is `server1.*` for the first iteration, `server2.*` for the second and so on.  Then each iteration will change only exactly one line and you should get your required result.